# MySQL error 1210

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I just got a nice facebook chat style shoutbox which I want to use in my site but it seems that the script has some errors.  It would be so kind if you guys have a look on it

I am really getting confused how to debug this... It's showing

**Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1210 Incorrect arguments to mysqld_stmt_execute**

I don't have any idea where is the error happening in the script.

Comment: This question is very badly titled..

Answer (score 0):

Found a post with similar issue that seemed to be because of MySQL. It suggested updating MySQL version. Is this a possibility for you?

[mysqli bind_param giving error: (1210) Incorrect arguments to mysql_stmt_execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053955/mysqli-bind-param-giving-error-1210-incorrect-arguments-to-mysql-stmt-execute)

Comment: Is this possible on shared hosting? @Tomi

Comment: Some providers might offer few different versions of MySQL server, but if that is not your case then most likely no.

Comment: well... depends how much they want your business, suggest that they upgrade, otherwise search for providers who are upgraded and the system will work with them :)